# Trait deref constraint

Tags: rust

I am trying to use https://github.com/japaric/blue-pill with a different microcontroller crate (https://github.com/nikhilkalige/stm32f411). I am getting build errors when I try to do this.

```
unsafe impl TIM for TIM3 {
   |             ^^^ expected struct `stm32f411::tim3::RegisterBlock`, found struct `stm32f411::tim2::RegisterBlock`
   |
   = note: expected type `stm32f411::tim3::RegisterBlock`
              found type `stm32f411::tim2::RegisterBlock`
   = note: required by `timer::TIM`
```

I am having a hard time understanding why this would compile in the first place when used without changing the microcontroller crate. The trait is implemented as below

```
/// IMPLEMENTATION DETAIL
pub unsafe trait TIM: Deref<Target = tim2::RegisterBlock> {
    /// IMPLEMENTATION DETAIL
    type GPIO: Deref<Target = gpioa::RegisterBlock>;
}

unsafe impl TIM for TIM2 {
    type GPIO = GPIOA;
}

unsafe impl TIM for TIM3 {
    type GPIO = GPIOA;
}

unsafe impl TIM for TIM4 {
    type GPIO = GPIOB;
}
```

So when you implement `TIM` for `TIM3` should it not access `tim3::RegisterBlock`? and the same for `type GPIO = GPIOB`